# Android : How to synchronized resource in right way

Tags: java, android, multithreading, file, synchronized

My application sometimes should read and write to file. And this work might happen in multithread, so I should synchronize those resource. Here is my code :

```
// write to file
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("data.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
synchronized (fos) {
     ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);       
     // continue to write
}

// read to file
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("data.dat");
synchronized (fis) {
    ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    // continue to read
}
```

does above code safe ? that means "data.dat" always just can read or write, and just in one thread ? If wrong, please correct for me.

Thanks :)

Comment: There are 2 issues: the 2 locks are not the same so reading and writing the file is not mutually exclusive. More importantly you seem to be using a local variable as a lock which completely defeats the purpose: each thread will have a different lock and concurrent accesses won't be blocked.

Comment: @assylias so, can you recommend ideas please. I cannot just only synchronize the method, because maybe another thread can access those resource, without using those method. Thanks :)

Comment: Assuming these are instance methods (i.e. non static), you can declare a `private final Object lock = new Object();` in your class, and use that as a lock. That way all accesses by all threads to those two portions of code will be exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use file locking: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking to tell other threads that output file is in use. If output file is exclusively used by your app then `synchronized` should prevent other threads from doing that portion of code at the same time. Or, finally, you can consider using `IntentService` to queue requests and handle them one by one

Comment: If I use `FileLock`, both different threads and processes will wait until the resource has been unlocked, right ? Or, they will throws exception ? Thanks :)

Comment: it depends on your implementation as lock is something your code needs to handle. You just try to obtain lock on certain resource (i.e. file) if you get it then you do your task and then release the lock. If you cannot get the lock, then you can wait and retry or throw exception or do anything else. It's up to you